# Replace a specific word with the value from another column

Tags: python, regex, pandas, replace

I've the following dataframe:

[image]

What I am trying to do is to add the vlaue from Col_1 after the word "Draft".

Basically, I need the following output:

[image]

For that I am trying with the following code:

```
df['Col_3'] = df['Col_2'].str.replace(r'Draft', ' Draft' + df['Col_1'].astype(str), regex=True)
```

But it gives me the following error:

```
 raise TypeError("repl must be a string or callable")
TypeError: repl must be a string or callable
```

How can I do this?

Thanks!

Comment: Please don't use images in your questions to show the dataframes!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
df['Col3'] = df.apply(lambda x: x['Col2'].replace("Draft", "Draft {}".format(x['Col1'])), axis=1)
```

or using `fstrings`

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "val": ["AAA", "BBB"],
        "str": [
            "Draft I promise not to use pictures in my next question",
            "Draft jk ill most likely post more pics"]})


df["output"] = df[["str", "val"]].apply(
    lambda x: x["str"].replace("Draft", f"Draft {x['val']} "), axis=1
)

print(df['output'])

0    Draft AAA  I promise not to use pictures in my...
1         Draft BBB  jk ill most likely post more pics
Name: output, dtype: object
```

Comment: @Datanovice that's a better example indeed! :D

Answer (score 0):

I think you need this:

```
df['Col2'] = df['Col2'].str[:5] + " " + df['Col1'] + " " + df['Col2'].str[5:]
```

or use `[str.slice][1]`

```
df['Col2'] = df['Col2'].str.slice(0, 5) + " " + df['Col1'] + " " + df['Col2'].str.slice(5)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try this :

```
df['Col_3'] = 'Draft ' + df['Col_1'] + df['Col_2'].str.replace('Draft', '')
```